# Why do I get undefined offset when not listing all the rows in foreach?

Tags: php, excel, laravel, query-builder

I have a problem when trying to import some excel data into the database with query builder, I got undefined offset: 4 even though the column of data I have is more than 4. The data: [excel data](http://www.mediafire.com/file/yimdky3gkzah4bh/template.xlsx/file). Is there something I should know about foreach?

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    $no = 1;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        DB::table('data_train')->insert([
            'no_pendaftaran' => $no,
            'nama' => $row[1],
            'jalur' => $row[4],
            'tahun' => $row[5],
            'daftar_kembali' => $row[10],
        ]);
        $no++;
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
```

The var_dump($row) output: [txt var_dump](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bglpvw3dwueqkak/foreach.txt/file)

Comment: What does the content of `$row` look like?

Comment: @Alex I have edited the post with var_dump output

Comment: Please include such information directly in your question in text form - properly formatted, and reduced to a sensible example, if too much data in general. Don’t dump stuff like this on external sites, where we have to _download_ it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'jalur' => $row[4] ?? null`

or use this for non nullable fields

`'jalur' => $row[4] ?? ''`

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't know the output of each iteration you should check first if the variable you are trying to insert actually has any data. Try something like:

```
'jalur' => (! empty($row[4])) ? $row[4] : null,
```

Same principal applies to all your insert fields.

Make sure your db fields accept `nullable`  otherwise replace `null` with `''`

Comment: Thank you, but I got unexpected , when I add , for each line. The @kheengz's answer did works

Comment: You have to put a comma after each of them :) It's an array field after all, edited my answer